# Unable to change PSN accounts

Tags: ps3, psn

Previously I created a PSN account but didn't think the details through. So I created a new one with different location and I wanted to change my user's account to it. But whenever I log out and try to log in the new account, I get "the email address you entered cannot be used". I would've expect it would send some confirmation email.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The email that you used to create the new account would have got a confirmation email to verify your account. If you didnt get it check your spam folder on your email account. If you still cant find it contact sony . (The email address has to be real or you cant verify your account)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did some more research and I found that once you've associated a user with a PSN account, you can't change it. The only option is to create another user and associate the new PSN with it. Sucks that I can't have all my saves and trophies in a single place, but hell. The main thing is enjoying the games.